# Check if any dropdownlist.selectedvalue in panel contains a certain value

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

I have a series of Dropdown boxes that contain an option for Pass or Fail. What I want to happen is if any of the 6 dropdown boxes in the panel contain a Fail selection, Button 1 appears. If there are no Fail selections made, then Button 2 appears.

Here is what I have, this doesn't seem to get all the selectedvalues of the dropdowns, only the first selection. I call the same CheckDDL() method after each DropDown_SelectedIndexChanged event. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
public void CheckDDL()
        {
            var myDropDownLists = TestResults.Controls
                .OfType<DropDownList>()
                .Where(ddl => ddl.Enabled = true);
            foreach (DropDownList ddl in myDropDownLists)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("result");
                string result = ddl.SelectedValue;
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["result"] = result;
                string fail = "0";
                bool containsfail = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(row => fail == row.Field<String>("result"));
                if (containsfail == true)
                {
                    btnAllPass.Visible = false;
                    btnAddredo.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                        btnAllPass.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
            }
    
  protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                CheckDDL();
            }
```

ASPX page code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="TestResults" runat="server" Width="1040px" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="2px" Height="280px">
            <br />
             <table id="HBredotable" style="width: 625px">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 189px" align="center">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Serial One:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 248px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="230px" Height="22px" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="165px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Pass" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Fail" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 189px" align="center">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Serial Two:"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 248px">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="230px" Height="22px" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="165px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Pass" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Fail" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 189px" align="center">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Serial Three:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 248px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="230px" Height="22px" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="165px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Pass" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Fail" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 189px" align="center">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Serial Four:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 248px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Width="230px" Height="22px" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="165px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Pass" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Fail" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 189px" align="center">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Serial Five:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 248px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Width="230px" Height="22px" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="165px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Pass" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Fail" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 189px" align="center">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Serial Six:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 248px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Width="230px" Height="22px" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="165px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList6_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Pass" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Fail" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblREDOerror" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="red"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnAllPass" runat="server" Text="All Tests Pass / Unit Complete"  Width="210px" OnClick="btnAllPass_Click"/>
            <asp:Button ID="btnAddredo" runat="server" Text="Enter Hashboards for REDO" Width="210px" OnClick="btnAddredo_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnconfirmredo" runat="server" Text="Yes, Continue" Width="210px" OnClick="btnconfirmredo_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnreturn" runat="server" Text="No, Go Back" Width="210px" OnClick="btnreturn_Click"  />
            <br />
        </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Can you also show the aspx code as well. I'm just wondering if you have dropdownlists nested inside a panel - then you will need to recurse into those.

Comment: I added the aspx code to the question. All dropdowns are indeed nested inside a panel. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I just tested that locally and my loop goes through each droplis fine. But its that you create a new DataTable in each loop.

I think this could be simplified with some Linq. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first off you are creating a new `DataTable` on each loop which means your code `bool containsfail = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(row => fail == row.Field<String>("result"));` is only checking the most recent droplist!

But I suggest you try this

```
            var myDropDownLists = TestResults.Controls
                .OfType<DropDownList>()
                .Where(ddl => ddl.Enabled = true);
            var anyFail = myDropDownLists.Any(dd => dd.SelectedValue == "0");
            btnAllPass.Visible = !anyFail;
            btnAddredo.Visible = anyFail;
```

you can fine tune the buttons to your liking.

Comment: I haven't fully tested it but I think this is a great answer! I appreciate the help! :)

Comment: I should maybe post a new question but in this same panel I have certain dropdown boxes disabled when the panel is displayed, however, when i select an option in the first dropdown, which causes a postback, all dropdowns become enabled. How can I keep the disabled dropdown disabled after a postback?

Comment: Create a new question for that please. Thx.

Comment: I created this question, sort of a two-parter--
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63582394/creating-datatable-from-textbox-dropdownlist-values

Answer (score 1):

Use `count` variable. If one of the dropdownlist contains `fail` then increment `count` to 1 and then check for `count`.

```
public void CheckDDL()
{
    var myDropDownLists = TestResults.Controls
    .OfType<DropDownList>()
    .Where(ddl => ddl.Enabled = true);
    int count=0;
    foreach (DropDownList ddl in myDropDownLists)
    {
        string result = ddl.SelectedValue;
        if(result=="fail")
        {
            count++;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
    if (count > 0)
    {
        btnAllPass.Visible = false;
        btnAddredo.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        btnAllPass.Visible = true;
    }
}
```