# Creating DataTable from textbox / dropdownlist values

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I am trying to create a datatable with two columns, "unit_serial" & "testresult". I have a panel with a table containing a column of textboxes with "unit_serial" and dropdownlist with option for Pass or Fail which is the "testresult". I often get mixed up when creating loops as to what should go inside and outside the loop so I'm sure that is my issue but I've tried every variation I could think of and I cannot get the data I'm looking for.  Here is what I have written. The sample data I'm working with should have at least 3 rows but I'm getting only 1.

I also have a separate issue with the same panel that I will include in this question as I'm sure it's something relatively simple. The dropdownlists in the panel are disabled unless the textbox field in the same table row is filled. When I make the first dropdownlist selection (which causes postback) all dropdown lists become enabled. How can I maintain the disabled status of the dropdowns after postback?

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("hbserial");
            dt.Columns.Add("test_result");
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            var myTextBoxes = TestResults.Controls
                .OfType<TextBox>()
                .Where(tb => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text));

            var myDropDownLists = TestResults.Controls
                .OfType<DropDownList>()
                .Where(ddl => ddl.SelectedValue != "--Select--");

            foreach (TextBox tb in myTextBoxes)
            {
                string hbserial = tb.Text;
                dr["hbserial"] = hbserial;
                foreach (DropDownList ddl in myDropDownLists)
                {
                    string testresult = ddl.SelectedValue;
                    dr["test_result"] = testresult;
                }

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
```

Here is my aspx page code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="TestResults" runat="server" Width="1040px" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="2px" Height="280px">
            <br />
             <table id="HBredotable" style="width: 625px">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 189px" align="center">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Serial One:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 248px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="230px" Height="22px" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="165px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Pass" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Fail" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 189px" align="center">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Serial Two:"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 248px">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="230px" Height="22px" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="165px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Pass" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Fail" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 189px" align="center">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Serial Three:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 248px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="230px" Height="22px" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="165px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Pass" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Fail" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 189px" align="center">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Serial Four:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 248px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Width="230px" Height="22px" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="165px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Pass" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Fail" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 189px" align="center">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Serial Five:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 248px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Width="230px" Height="22px" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="165px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Pass" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Fail" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 189px" align="center">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Serial Six:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 248px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Width="230px" Height="22px" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="165px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList6_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Pass" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Fail" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblREDOerror" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="red"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnAllPass" runat="server" Text="All Tests Pass / Unit Complete"  Width="210px" OnClick="btnAllPass_Click"/>
            <asp:Button ID="btnAddredo" runat="server" Text="Enter Hashboards for REDO" Width="210px" OnClick="btnAddredo_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnconfirmredo" runat="server" Text="Yes, Continue" Width="210px" OnClick="btnconfirmredo_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnreturn" runat="server" Text="No, Go Back" Width="210px" OnClick="btnreturn_Click"  />
            <br />
        </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably here in this nested loop:

```
foreach (TextBox tb in myTextBoxes)
            {
                string hbserial = tb.Text;
                dr["hbserial"] = hbserial;
                foreach (DropDownList ddl in myDropDownLists)
                {
                    string testresult = ddl.SelectedValue;
                    dr["test_result"] = testresult;
                }

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
```

You are looping over all the droplists from your or each textbox.

What you really want to do is fetch the droplist control matched with the textbox. It looks like the number at each matches so you can use that and `FindControl` to locate the droplist.

Something like this:

```
foreach (TextBox tb in myTextBoxes)
            {
                string hbserial = tb.Text;
                dr["hbserial"] = hbserial;
                var num = tb.ControlID.Substring("TextBox".Length-1);
                var droplistForTextBox = TestResults.FindControl<DropDownList>("DropDownList"+num);
                string testresult = ddl.SelectedValue;
                dr["test_result"] = testresult;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
```

NB: I've not tried the code above.

I do find it interesting that you are using a Datatable for local storage rather than a `List<>` or an `Array<>`. I'd recommend you look into those as a, IMHO, better way of storing this information.

Comment: I am ultimately creating the DataTable so I can do something like this:
`int rowcount = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x["testresult"].ToString() == "0").ToList().Count;`  I'm using `rowcount` as a Parameter in a stored procedure. Can I use `List<>` or `Array<>` in this manner?

Comment: I'm also using the DataTable to pass the "unit_serial" and "testresult" values to the stored procedure.

Comment: That can also be done with `List` or an `Array` but it's whatever work for you. Please to try the code above and mark as answer if it helped you.

Comment: This is my fault bc i tagged the question with asp.net but I am using WinForms and getting "Textbox does not contain a definition for ControlID" as well as a couple of other errors in this code. Could you revise your suggestion for WinForms? Much appreciated!! :)

Comment: You supplied the ASPX layout and you confused this with WinForms? Sadly I don't know WinForms.  I suggest you ask a new question with the proper tags and perhaps delete this question.